# Multiple file upload field option not uploading all the files

Tags: php, html, upload

I am working with the input `type="file" multiple="multiple"` and a PHP upload loop.

```
<input name="data[]" id="file" type="file" multiple="multiple" class="txtinput2" />
```

Above is my HTML, below is my PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['action'])=='uploadfiles'){
$count_data=count($_FILES['data']) ;   ######### count the data #####

for($x=0;$x<$count_data;$x++)
```

When I echo `count_data` it gives me an output of **5**, but when I select **28** files it says **28** files chosen in the input field. Does the `multiple="multiple"` only support **5** uploads?

I checked the PHP info and it says max file uploads **20**, max post size **8m** and max file size **128m** and the total size of all the files I am trying to upload is of **1.94 megs**.

```
Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => DSCF0960.jpg [1] => DSCF0961.jpg [2] => DSCF0963.jpg [3] => DSCF0964.jpg [4] => DSCF0966.jpg [5] => DSCF0967.jpg [6] => DSCF0968.jpg [7] => DSCF0969.jpg [8] => DSCF0970.jpg [9] => DSCF0971.jpg [10] => DSCF0972.jpg [11] => DSCF0973.jpg [12] => DSCF0974.jpg [13] => DSCF0975.jpg [14] => DSCF0976.jpg [15] => DSCF0977.jpg [16] => DSCF0978.jpg [17] => DSCF0979.jpg [18] => DSCF0980.jpg [19] => DSCF0981.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg [1] => image/jpeg [2] => image/jpeg [3] => image/jpeg [4] => image/jpeg [5] => image/jpeg [6] => image/jpeg [7] => image/jpeg [8] => image/jpeg [9] => image/jpeg [10] => image/jpeg [11] => image/jpeg [12] => image/jpeg [13] => image/jpeg [14] => image/jpeg [15] => image/jpeg [16] => image/jpeg [17] => image/jpeg [18] => image/jpeg [19] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /tmp/php4uI9g8 [1] => /tmp/phpVx5WrZ [2] => /tmp/php2DbRCQ [3] => /tmp/phpT2gSNH [4] => /tmp/phpPDlZYy [5] => /tmp/phpMzCcaq [6] => /tmp/phpRxkwlh [7] => /tmp/phpgoRWw8 [8] => /tmp/phpYlGsIZ [9] => /tmp/phpYBG1TQ [10] => /tmp/phpTQBD5H [11] => /tmp/phpQesphz [12] => /tmp/php5U4dtq [13] => /tmp/phpp2G5Eh [14] => /tmp/phpwaZZQ8 [15] => /tmp/php4W0W2Z [16] => /tmp/php7g3WeR [17] => /tmp/phpeZj0qI [18] => /tmp/phpAGo6Cz [19] => /tmp/phpbXlfPq ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 [8] => 0 [9] => 0 [10] => 0 [11] => 0 [12] => 0 [13] => 0 [14] => 0 [15] => 0 [16] => 0 [17] => 0 [18] => 0 [19] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 79605 [1] => 75839 [2] => 71245 [3] => 63228 [4] => 64201 [5] => 74440 [6] => 75350 [7] => 73367 [8] => 72491 [9] => 69725 [10] => 75508 [11] => 72755 [12] => 76076 [13] => 72140 [14] => 68745 [15] => 77859 [16] => 74281 [17] => 74613 [18] => 71702 [19] => 75916 ) )
```

Comment: check you POST limit on the server side.

Comment: What's the result of `print_r($_FILES['data'])`?

Comment: Comment too long, posted Edit in original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a total of 20 files in your array divided into 5 sub-array which according to what you've said in your question is your limit of upload.

> I checked the PHP info and it says max file uploads 20

The first array is the old file name of each file in order.
The second array is the file type of each file in order.
The third array is where the file was saved and its temporary name.
The fourth array is if any file failed to upload or not, I assume it will be either 0 or 1 being 0 no errors.
The last array is the file size of each file in order.

You count all the files using:

```
$count_data=count($_FILES['data']['name']) -1;
```

And read it like this:

```
for($i=0; $i < $count_data; $i++)
{
    if ($_FILES['data']['error'][$i] == 0)
    {
        $name = $_FILES['data']['name'][$i];
        $temp = $_FILES['data']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $type = $_FILES['data']['type'][$i];
        $size = $_FILES['data']['size'][$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that, thanks sir 

for people looking, changed count($_FILES['data']['name'])